# how can I install "elm-light" on windows?

Tags: elm

[elm-light](https://github.com/rundis/elm-light) looks like a great plugin for elm in the LightTable editor, but I can't make it work properly on Windows.  When I try to [establish a connection](https://rundis.gitbooks.io/elm-light-guide/content/elm-client-overview.html), I get this error : `Path must be a string. Received null`.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Avoid spaces in the path to the elm-platform**

- type `echo %path%` in a Windows command prompt to check the Elm path
- uninstall and reinstall elm in another folder if necessary

**Avoid spaces in the path to LightTable**

- move the LightTable folder if necessary
- uninstall and reinstall the elm plugin in the new location

**Install elm-oracle**

- execute `npm install elm-oracle` in a Windows command prompt to get auto-complete to work.

**Install [elm-format](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format)**

**Configure [keymaps](https://rundis.gitbooks.io/elm-light-guide/content/reference.html)**

- use `ctrl-` (Windows) instead of `cmd` (iOS) in the keychords

Comment: - You don't need to use elm-oracle. The plugin (since 0.4) uses a custom parser to get much richer information than elm-oracle can provide. (Also older versions came bundled with elm-oracle, so that step has never been required)

Answer (score 1):

"Path must be a string" should already be [fixed](https://github.com/rundis/elm-light/issues/29) in elm-light-0.42

### AST

> Auto-completions only starts working once you have connected to an Elm project. You can force "suto.connection", through various commands (Lint, toggle docs etc). So if you hit "ctrl-d" on a symbol when you aren't connected, it will connect for you. Another option is to add the Lint command to the save operation in Light Table. Again see Useful configurations
>   -- https://rundis.gitbooks.io/elm-light-guide/content/chapter1.html

After opening elm file in Light Table, you can see at the status: `AST not connected`. That means elm-light doesn't run yet.

You have to connect manually either by running `ctrl+space > ELM: Load/reload project AST` or better by [mapping](https://rundis.gitbooks.io/elm-light-guide/content/misc.html) this action to save.

To do this, run `ctrl-space > Settings: User keymap`. Add line `[:editor.elm "ctrl-s" :save :elm-format :elm.lint]` before last `]` so it looks like this:

```clj
[
 ;; ...
 [:editor.elm "ctrl-s" :save :elm-format :elm.lint]
]
```

Above mapping to `ctrl-s` will also format and lint your file.

One more thing. If you type for example `import Dict as Dict exposing (`, AST will report error. For that we need to automatic brackets close. To do that, run `ctrl-space > Settings: User behaviors` and add line `[:editor :lt.objs.editor/autoclose-brackets]`, so that the file looks like that:

```clj
[
 ;; ...
 [:editor :lt.objs.editor/autoclose-brackets]
]
```